# Converting large SCN to Tiff

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I am having difficulty converting the .scn file found here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JQBT-a6icoRiJ7ljSNr6_2Fi1IdOjZVZ/view?usp=sharing to a tiff and/or jpeg image format. The file is about 3GB The following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

slide = 'KBR-20X-S8.scn'


def get_scence_num(img_file):
    slide = slideio.open_slide(img_file, "SCN")
    return slide.num_scenes


def get_img(img_file, scene_num):
    slide = slideio.open_slide(img_file, "SCN")
    scene = slide.get_scene(scene_num)
    return scene.read_block()

print('Loading Image Data')
image = get_img(slide, 1)
print('Image data finished loading. Reshaping data')
image = image.reshape(-1,)
print('Reshaping complete. Splitting Array')
#newarr = np.array_split(image,3)
#image.save('test.tif')
print('Saving in progress')
plt.imsave('test.jpeg',image )
#plt.show()
```

I am getting the following errors when I try different things

`numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 59.4 GiB for an array with shape (15949892010,) and data type float32`

`OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: The SVS file is in BigTIFF format, a 64bit version of TIFF. The Image data are stored in as JPEG compressed tiles in the BigTIFF file. The uncompressed base layer is too large to fit into RAM at once or be converted to JPEG. Instead of converting to another format, use libraries such as pyvips, openslide, slideio, or tifffile to read/process the image in smaller parts.